# Customize List.aspx for One Table in ASP Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I have just meticulously followed [MS instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488540.aspx) for customising a dynamic data page template for one table.  Create the folder `CustomPages/MyTable/List.aspx`, and copy PageTemplates/List.aspx into that folder, but I now get compiler error because I have duplicated methods in both List.aspx files.

What am I doing wrong?

**Just in:**  I found another, non-MS page that I can't find again now, but he suggested the almost obvious: to change the class name in thej 3 files of my custom list page.

Comment: a link to the *instructions* you're following would help

Comment: @JohnIdol, I've now linked to the MS instructions and explained a solution to the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what it says in the instructions, but you'll need to change the namespace in the two codebehind files (List.aspx.cs and List.aspx.designer.cs) and in the "inherits" reference in the .aspx file or yes, you will have duplicate methods (same namespace, same class name, same method name).

You should change the namespace to reflect the path that the custom page is in - this will help ensure it stays unique.